# How to get the AppData folder in C# under Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, appdata, special-folders, application-data

I have always gotten the AppData folder using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

However, on my Windows 10 test machine this returns `"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming"` not `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming"` as on all other versions of Windows.

What do I need to call for **Windows 10**?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between those paths? What do you mean by "User" and "<user>"? Do you mean the former is literally "User" instead of the username?

Comment: Your code snippet should work. Are you logged into the test machine as the user named "User"?

Comment: I have logged on as an administrator and as a normal user.  In both cases I get literally "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming".  I have run the test on other machines and it works.  So there is something specific about this machine.  I suspect it is related to upgrading from Win7.  The other machines all upgraded from Win 8.1